# (SSL)windows secure Channel doesn't allow pemkeyfile has password

Tags: mongodb, ssl, mongo-c-driver

if I compile the c driver with `-DENABLE_SSL=WINDOWS` (windows secure Channel), connection would be failed if the client pem key file has password.

the error info of log:

---

> [error@stream-secure-channel] Failed to parse private key. ASN1 bad tag value me
>   t.
>   (0x8009310B)
>   [warning@stream-secure-channel] a client certificate has been requested
>
> ---

note:

1. I create the private key for the pem file with this command: 
   openssl genrsa -des3 -out server.key 2048 , and then input password : 1234

   using mongo.exe , I can connect with the same pem file and password from   my own working computer successfully:
   mongo --host 10.154.10.39 --ssl --authenticationDatabase admin --username user1 -p 123 --sslCAFile d:/ca.pem --sslPEMKeyFile d:/cry.pem --sslPEMKeyPassword 1234

   however, if my program uses the mongocxx driver, always get failed.
2. if I use the driver which is compiled with "-DENABLE_SSL=OPENSSL", this issue dissapears.

Comment: windows crypto uses the pkcs7 format, not PEM.  If you create your cert in that format, it should work (MSDN: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/SecCertEnroll/pkcs--7-attributes)  (a cert vendor:https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9474/69/how-do-i-create-a-pem-file-from-the-certificates-i-received-from-you)